# Are threads reused between requests on server methods?

Tags: thread-safety, devforce

We have a server method where we enforce the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture according to the language of the user to ensure that the returned values will be properly translated.

However we are unsure whether this thread could be used to fullfil the request of another user (in a different language). We want to be sure that this approach is properly working if there are a lot of parallel requests on this server method.

Comment: What kind of server method is this?  Is it called by an InvokeServerMethod call, part of an EntityQueryInterceptor or ?

Comment: It is called using InvokeServerMethod

Comment: OK, the thread created, by either the remoting infrastructure of WCF depending on your configuration, will have a lifetime of the request itself.  The request thread is "dedicated" to that specific request/user until complete.  Don't do async calls within your invoked method, since they may not return to the same thread.  Otherwise, setting the culture per user request should be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer